# Removing the strings between two characters in excel

Tags: excel

I have a large excel data sheet with thousands of rows and its filled with html codes with less than and greater than tags containing codes and other real information is outside of tags. Like;

```
    Cables Supported                                      </TD>        <td class="specDetail fs18" data-selenium="specDetail">         RG-6 coax              </TD>       </TR>                               <tr>        <td class="specTopic fs18" data-selenium="specTopic">         Weight Supported                                      </TD>        <td class="specDetail fs18" data-selenium="specDetail">         80 lb (36 kg)              </TD>       </TR>               </TBODY>   </TABLE>      <table class="specTable" data-selenium="specTable">   <tbody data-selenium="specBody">   <tr>    <th class="specHeader Header" colspan="2" data-selenium="specHeader">     <a name="shipping" class="fs32 OpenSans-300-normal" id="shipping" data-selenium="specHeaderLink">Packaging Info</A>    </TH>   </TR>      <tr>    <td class="specTopic fs18" data-selenium="specTopic">     Package Weight    </TD>    <td class="specDetail fs18" data-selenium="specDetail">     0.05 lb    </TD>   </TR>      <tr>    <td class="specTopic fs18" data-selenium="specTopic">     Box Dimensions (LxWxH)    </TD>    <td class="specDetail fs18" data-selenium="specDetail">     3.3 x 2.0 x 0.2"    </TD>   </TR>      </TBODY>  </TABLE>       </DIV>                            </DIV>             <div class="rightPanel">                                                        <div class="video-container">                     <div class="content" data-selenium="content">    <script src="//players.brightcove.net/1661991858001/N1cfLQmFe_default/index.min.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT> </DIV><!-- end content -->              </DIV>             </DIV>                                       </DIV>
```

I need to remove everything inside "<" ">" including the less than and greater than characters. So at the end, result should look like this:

```
Cables Supported RG-6 coax Weight Supported 80 lb (36 kg) Package Weight 0.05 lb
Box Dimensions (LxWxH)  3.3 x 2.0 x 0.2"
```

Data to columns won't with that large data. It just doesn't fit. I'm stuck.

Comment: do a quick find/replace from the ribbon.  Use Find: `<*>` and replace it with nothing.

Comment: That worked nicely. Thank you, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

i cant write the formula properly freehand and dont currently have access to excel so this may need some name function name changing and possibly attribute order changing but it would look something like

```
=replace(a1, left(right(a1, find(a1,"<")),find(a1,">")),"")
```

which should do the following in pseudo code

```
s = string
m = position of first >
n = position of first <
o = the text to the left of the m'th letter of s
p = the text to the right of the n'th letter of o
replace p from s with ""
```

then copy the column with the formula in and past special (values) into the original string column until there are no more < or > (or record a macro to do that then either spam the key or edit it and surround the macro with a loop.